# Replace N number of string.Empty from a string

Tags: c#, string

I have to replace white spaces with " " on a string (which can be variable in length). If this were all I need to do it would be easy, but I need to only replace white spaces at the start of a sentence/paragraph.

I thought that creating a sub-string of only the  white spaces could help, but the problem I face is that there is not a unique character that start all paragraph/sentences.

How can I replace white spaces from a paragraph but only those at the beginning of it?

Example:

< >< >< >< >< >< >    Hello World of strings and replacements.

Reference: Each < > stands for a white space, because the text editor on this site won't allow white spaces at the beginning of a sentence.

I want to remove the < > only

Comment: there is a difference between `string.Empty which is ""` and a space which is `" "`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UhL3YI

Comment: @Patrick, do not need to trim it but to replace string.Empty with "&#160;"

Comment: @ElPadrino Then please edit your OP because it's very ambiguous, you say you want to replace white spaces and then you say you only care about `string.Empty`

Comment: you can't replace `string.Empty` with anything - it isn't there. `string.Empty` is literally no characters. There is an infinite amount of zero characters between each and every character.

Comment: What you *really* want, it seems, is "remove white space from beginnings of sentences", and then you must first define what a sentence is to you.

Comment: @MethodMan I'm interested in white spaces only.

Comment: @Mat, thanks for noticing my error, just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var myString = "        Hello World .  ";

var countOfSpaces = myString.TakeWhile(c => c.Equals(' ')).Count();

var newString = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("&#160;", countOfSpaces)) + myString.Substring(countOfSpaces);
```

DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/376Fmk

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
string newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, "^\\s+|\\s+$", "");
```

EDIT: You can change the Regex pattern, depending on your needs:

- `^\\s+` - Whitespace at the beginning of the string.
- `\\s+$` - Whitespace at the end of the string.
- `^\\s+|\\s+$` - A combination that will match either of the other two patterns.

EDIT 2: To replace the characters rather than remove them, you can do the following:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(oldString, "^\\s+");
string newString = new StringBuilder(m.Value.Length)
                           .Insert(0, "&$160;", m.Value.Length)
                           .ToString() +     
                       oldString.Substring(m.Value.Length);
```

Comment: I haven't thought of takling it this way. The problem I see is that I need to replace each white space with "&#160;" If there are 30, I replace 30. If there 7 I will have to replace 7.

Comment: @ElPadrino See edit.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. I will try to use this solution to replace tab spaces instead of white spaces; which is another feature I need to deliver.